# Grounds in a linear bipolar power supply for audio?

Tags: power-supply, mains, grounding, ground-loop

I've purchased a linear power supply, as surplus, from a local electronics dealer.  It's a Condor AA15-0.8, made to supply ±15VDC at 0.8A or ±12V at 1A; as far as I can tell, it's a standard regulated design (though quite old; the regulator chips are actually UA723s, for instance). The metal frame/chassis of the power supply is not electrically connected to the output common/ground.

> [image: A photograph of the mentioned power supply.]
>
> (Photo taken from an online auction.)

The difficulty comes in connecting the thing to wall power.  I'm in the US, so the intent is the standard wall 110VAC, and the transformer's lugs are already jumpered for that. The writing on the chassis recommends a 0.5A fuse.  My current intent is to solder to the transformer lugs a fused IEC socket, so I can mount the socket and supply solidly into a wooden case.  I've got a Corcom 5EFM4S for this purpose (which incidentally includes a switch and RF filters); as I understand it, I just need to connect the transformer lugs to either the D and F terminals or the C and E terminals --

[image: Schematic of the 5EFM4S; the neutral wire goes through an LCR filter and an optional fuse to (if the module is configured for 120V) terminals B, C, and D; the phase wire goes through the filter and a fuse to terminals E and F.]

-- but I am concerned about grounding. The 5EFM4S filter has capacitors that connect from each line to a common ground.  By the schematic, that ground is also the IEC cable's mains ground, and both connect to terminal G.

Because this is going to be used in an audio application (I'm meaning to use it to power DIY and commercial Eurorack modular synthesizer modules), I have heard a lot of conflicting things about grounding; for instance, I've read that I shouldn't ground the chassis to avoid ground loops, and I've read that I *should* ground the chassis for safety. If I should ground the chassis, I'm not sure *which* ground it should use -- the output common, or the socket's terminal G.  I don't know whether to connect that terminal G to the DC common, either.

Part of the concern is that I'm intending to connect the modules powered by this to separately powered systems, and I've heard, but only vaguely, about damage being caused by systems having grounds at differing potentials.  If there's not a clear-cut answer to these questions, are there resources out there to help in understanding these problems and making these decisions?

Comment: Unrelated to grounding, but for a North American *120V* supply you'd connect to D-F **AND** C-D, not D-F **or** C-D.

Comment: @brhans From my understanding of the schematic (and probing the thing), when the module is set to 120V, C and D are internally shorted, as are E and F.  Would it be best to tie both pairs across to the transformer lugs anyway?

Comment: Ok - as long as that jumpering arrangement is still in place then powering C-D or E-F would be fine.